# Download Video from Url using Retrofit

Tags: android, video-streaming, download, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for consuming web services and so far its great. But does Retrofit provide a way to download videos from URLs?

I checked this link but the `@Streaming` annotation is not available anymore.[Retro fit Image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158321/use-retrofit-to-download-image-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can use the @Streaming annotation which is available as of version 1.6.0.  Make sure you use that version.

As specified in the [changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-160-2014-06-06):
New: @Streaming on a Response type will skip buffering the body to a byte[] before delivering.

```
interface Api {        
    @Get("path/to/your/resource") 
    @Streaming
    Response getData();
}
```

You should then be able to stream directly from the InputStream like so

```
Response response = api.getData()
InputStream is = response.getBody().in();
// stream your data directly from the InputStream!
```

Keep in mind that my example is synchronous for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

To complete @Miguel Lavigne answer here is how to do it with Retrofit 2 :

```
interface Service {
    @GET("path/to/your/resource")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}


Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getData();
try {
    InputStream is = call.execute().body().byteStream();
    (...)
} catch (IOException e) {...}
```