# How to download file in Android using Retrofit library?

Tags: android, download, retrofit

I need to download all types of file (binary, image, text, etc) using Retrofit library in my app. All the examples on the net is using HTML GET method. I need to use POST to prevent automatic caching.

My question is how to download a file using POST method in Retrofit?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878478/how-to-download-file-in-android-using-retrofit-library/36682027#36682027

Comment: Don't try this :) It's the second answer to the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use @Streaming

**Asynchronous**

**EDIT 1**

```
//On your api interface
@POST("path/to/your/resource")
@Streaming
void apiRequest(Callback<POJO> callback);

restAdapter.apiRequest(new Callback<POJO>() {
        @Override
        public void success(POJO pojo, Response response) {
            try {
                //you can now get your file in the InputStream
                InputStream is = response.getBody().in();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

**Synchronous**

```
//On your api interface
@POST("path/to/your/resource")
@Streaming
Response apiRequest();

Response response = restAdapter.apiRequest();

try {
    //you can now get your file in the InputStream
    InputStream is = response.getBody().in();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try it and will get back to you.

Comment: That's an object class, you can change it to just `Object`

Comment: I get this error: Only methods having Response as data type are allowed to have @Streaming annotation. I'm using  asynchronous mode.

Comment: I solved it by changing POJO to Response class. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, the POJO there is just an example :)

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with retrofit 2.0.0 beta?

Comment: @Ehsan you can use Response (import retrofit.client.Response;) as model and get a String from that Response object .

Answer (score 55):

In `kotlin`, Do this:

In your service add method:

```
    @Streaming
    @GET
    suspend fun downloadFile(@Url fileUrl:String): Response<ResponseBody>
```

To call this method, from ViewModel:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
     val responseBody=yourServiceInstance.downloadFile(url).body()
     saveFile(responseBody,pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile)
}
```

To save file:

```
fun saveFile(body: ResponseBody?, pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile: String):String{
        if (body==null)
            return ""
        var input: InputStream? = null
        try {
            input = body.byteStream()
            //val file = File(getCacheDir(), "cacheFileAppeal.srl")
            val fos = FileOutputStream(pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile)
            fos.use { output ->
                val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // or other buffer size
                var read: Int
                while (input.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                }
                output.flush()
            }
            return pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e("saveFile",e.toString())
        }
        finally {
            input?.close()
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Note:

1. Make sure your `refrofit` client's base url and the url passed to downloadFile makes valid file url:

> Retrofit's Base url + downloadFile's method url = File url

2. Here I am using suspend keyword before `downloadFile` to call this from ViewModel, I have used `viewModelScope.launch {}` you can use different coroutine scope according to your caller end.
3. Now `pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile`, If you want to store file into project's file directory, you can do this:

> ```
> val fileName=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
> val pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile = myApplication.filesDir.absolutePath+fileName
> ```

4. If you are storing the downloaded file under file or cache directory, you don't need to acquire permission, otherwise for public storage, you know the process.

Comment: " Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"
-> this is the error I have got

Comment: after adding GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create(); and add it to addConverterFactory()  ifaced new error that Respone body has no argument

Answer (score 10):

This is How to DOWNLOAD file in Retrofit 2

```
public interface ServerAPI {
        @GET
        Call<ResponseBody> downlload(@Url String fileUrl);

        Retrofit retrofit =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://192.168.43.135/retro/") // REMEMBER TO END with /
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .build();

}

    //How To Call
public void download(){
        ServerAPI api = ServerAPI.retrofit.create(ServerAPI.class);
        api.downlload("http://192.168.43.135/retro/pic.jpg").enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File file = new File(path, "file_name.jpg");
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            IOUtils.write(response.body().bytes(), fileOutputStream);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile. You can't initialize things in an `Interface`.

Comment: did you try to compile it? it work for me, and this is how i used to

Comment: For IOUtils, add dependency  implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody() with no args 
This isTHE ERROR

Comment: @ugalisoft Can I pass a different URL for downloading using retrofit, that has no reference to the base URL configured for retrofit. Will it work that way?

Answer (score 10):

With Kotlin, it's little bit simple.

**API Service**

```kotlin
@GET
@Streaming
fun download(@Url url: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

**API Client**

```kotlin
object ApiClient {
    private val retrofit = ...

    val service: ApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

**Download Function**

```kotlin
fun download(urlString: String, target: File) {
    val response = ApiClient.service.download(urlString).execute()
    response.body()?.byteStream()?.use {
        target.parentFile?.mkdirs()
    
        FileOutputStream(target).use { targetOutputStream ->
            it.copyTo(targetOutputStream)
        }
    } ?: throw RuntimeException("failed to download: $urlString")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Retrofit 2.0.0, you can refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441111/2998877) under the question -- [Use retrofit to download image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158321/use-retrofit-to-download-image-file).

The key point is use `okhttp3.ReponseBody` to receive the raw binary data, not any POJO.

And you want to use `POST` method to get the file, it's easy, just change `@GET` to `@POST`, but it depend whether your server support the `POST` method!

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code for downloading with progress (Kotlin)

Retrofit Api Service

```
@Streaming
@GET
fun downloadFile(@Url fileUrl: String): Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>
```

make sure you add `@Streaming` for large file downloading

And paste below code in your Activity or Fragment

```
fun downloadfileFromRetrofit() {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("ENTER_YOUR_BASE_URL")
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build()
    val downloadService = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi::class.java)

   downloadService.downloadFile("FILE_URL_PATH").observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe({
            val task = object : AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
                override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
                    val writtenToDisk =writeResponseBodyToDisk(it.body()!!)
                    println("file download was a success? $writtenToDisk")
                    return null
                }
            }
            task.execute()
        }, {
            print(it.message)
        })
}
```

below is the writeResponseBodyToDisk method

```
fun writeResponseBodyToDisk(body: ResponseBody): Boolean {
    val appDirectoryName = "YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME"
    val filename = "YOUR_FILE_NAME"
    val apkFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename)
    try {

        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
            val fileSize = body.contentLength()
            var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(apkFile)
            while (true) {
                val read = inputStream!!.read(fileReader)
                if (read == -1) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()

           calulateProgress(fileSize.toDouble(),fileSizeDownloaded.toDouble()
                println("file downloading $fileSizeDownloaded of $fileSize")

            outputStream.flush()

            return true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.toString())
            return false
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream!!.close()
            }
            outputStream?.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e.toString())
        return false
    }

}
```

below method is for calculate progress

```
 fun calulateProgress(totalSize:Double,downloadSize:Double):Double{
    return ((downloadSize/totalSize)*100)
}
```

Comment: This solution requires RxJava and AsyncTask.

Comment: And why would you use AsyncTask when you have RxJava?

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer or better, why would you use RxJava or even AsyncTask, when you can use Kotlin Coroutines? :D

Comment: If you read this, please, don't use the answer above. It mixes different programming approaches without any advantage. This makes your application susceptible to bugs, errors, missing readability, etc...

Comment: If there is a better way, post the alternative

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code for downloading the any type of file using retrofit ...

```
 File file = new File("Your_File_path/name");

  private void startDownload() {

    if (!NetWorkUtils.getInstance(context).isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No data connection available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(FILE_BASE_URL)
            .build();

    FileHandlerService handlerService = retrofit.create(FileHandlerService.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = handlerService.downloadFile(mFileName);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body())) {
                    listener.onFileLoaded(file);
                }
            } else {
                listener.onDownloadFailed("Resource not Found");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            listener.onDownloadFailed("Download Failed");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}


interface FileHandlerService {

    @GET("uploads/documents/{file_name}")
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(
            @Path("file_name") String imageName);
}

private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works on my android 5.1 but not on others. I have tested it in android 6 and doesn't work 0

Answer (score 1):

Include following function in MainActivity.java:

```
void getRetrofitImage() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitImageAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitImageAPI.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getImageDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {

                Log.d("onResponse", "Response came from server");

                boolean FileDownloaded = DownloadImage(response.body());

                Log.d("onResponse", "Image is downloaded and saved ? " + FileDownloaded);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

File handling part of Image download will be:

```
private boolean DownloadImage(ResponseBody body) {

    try {
        Log.d("DownloadImage", "Reading and writing file");
        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = body.byteStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DownloadImage",e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }

        int width, height;
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");
        width = 2*bMap.getWidth();
        height = 6*bMap.getHeight();
        Bitmap bMap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, width, height, false);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap2);

        return true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DownloadImage",e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can see this for full tutorial: [Image Download using Retrofit 2.0](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-retrofit-android-example-download-image-url-display-android-device-screen/)

Answer (score 0):

The request declaration for downloading files looks like this given below

```
// option 1: a resource relative to your base URL
@GET("/resource/example.zip")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithFixedUrl();

// option 2: using a dynamic URL
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Url String fileUrl);
```

After declaring your request call like this

```
FileDownloadService downloadService = ServiceGenerator.create(FileDownloadService.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = downloadService.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(fileUrl);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "server contacted and has file");

            boolean writeToDisk = writeToDisk(response.body());

            Log.d(TAG, "file downloaded " + writtenToDisk);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "server error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error");
    }
});
```

Also implement this method to file into your sdcard.

```
private boolean writeToDisk(ResponseBody body) {  
    try { File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "ProfileImage");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("ProfileImage", "Oops! Failed create "
                        + "ProfileImage" + " directory");
            }
        }
        File futureStudioIconFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "userImage.png");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```