# How to make an Android REST client to post videos/images to a Jersey web service?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I have a functional web service in Jersey, that consumes a multi part form data like videos and images and stores them on a directory. I am able to upload videos and images from a browser. Now I want to upload them from an Android application by selecting from gallery Intent or camera.
How am I supposed to do so?
Any help will be appreciated. Here is my web service code.

```
@Path("/fileupload")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        try {

            String uploadedFileLocation = "/home/aamir/Downloads/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

            // save it
            saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

            String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: " + uploadedFileLocation;

            return output;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return "error";
        }

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void saveToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = null;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Retrofit to download the image.  It's a great library for handling RESTful applications:

[Use retrofit to download image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158321/use-retrofit-to-download-image-file)

Comment: I am not interested in downloading the image, but to upload it, that too from an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jersey client API in your Android app (or any other client API for that matter, Apache CXF springs to mind...). It lives in a standalone jar which you can add to your app as a dependency, then in your app create a shared client which you use to create requests.

From the Jersey client docs...

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target =  client.target("http://localhost:9998").path("resource");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("x", "foo");
form.param("y", "bar");

MyJAXBBean bean =
    target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                  MyJAXBBean.class);
```

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html